# Use multiple keywords to display results from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, database

EDIT......I have a normalized database which is based on a learning environment. 
I would like to be able to search for a selection of keywords which are in a table called 'C_Search' and use them to pull up the course details which stored in 'C_Info'. I have a basic search function but it is driving me crazy with how to get the keywords involved as I am new to all this and trying to learn as I go along...sometimes we need help

These are the relevant tables and the fields in them.

### C_Info

Course_ID
Course_Name
C_Description
C_Duration
C_Cost
C_Entry_Req
C_Assessment_Type
C_Progression
C_Type

### C_Search

Course_ID
C_Key_Words
C_NLC_Ref_No
Awarding_Body
C_UCAS_Code

There are a list of keywords separated by a coma. I would like to use them to allow users to search the database for available courses.

I know I have posted this before but some of the answers were confusing and I'm struggling to learn as it is.

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "jimbooth_test","test1")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("jimbooth_groupproject");
// first part of the main query (with dummy WHERE operator so you can then use AND operators)
$query .= " AND C_Description like '%{$keyword_row['keyword']}%'";
// query the keywords
$res1 = mysql_query("select keyword from C_Search") or trigger_error(mysql_error()
// loop through rows and add conditions to the main query
while ($keyword_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {
    $query .= " AND C_Description like '%{$keyword_row['keyword']}%'";
}
$res2 = mysql_query($query);
die($query);
if (mysql_num_rows($res2) <= 0) {
// no results
echo 'Sorry, No results found.';
} else
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res2)){
    echo '<br/> <B>Course Title:</B> '.$row['Course_Name'];
    echo '<br/> <B>Course Info:</B> '.$row['C_Description'];
    echo '<br/> <B>Duration:</B> '.$row['C_Duration'];
    echo '<br/> <B>Entry Requirements:</B> '.$row['C_Entry_Req'];
    echo '<br/> <B>Course Cost: '.$row['C_Cost'];
        echo '<br/> <B>Course Progression: '.$row['C_Progression'];    
    echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: if you want to pass the query you should do 1=1 or just remove the 1.

Also use PDO or mysqli instead of mysql because it is deprecated

Comment: use query $query = "select * from C_Info";

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query is failing:

> "select keyword from C_Search"

Which means that $res1 is not a result. Instead, it is a boolean FALSE value. mysql_fetch_assoc expects a resource. Are you sure that C_Info exists and that you haven't made any typos?

Try adding:

```
$res1 = mysql_query("select keyword from C_Search") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

Tell us if any errors are spit out onto the screen.

**PS**: The people telling you remove the WHERE 1 don't seem to realize that you're doing this:

```
$query .= " AND C_Description like '%{$keyword_row['keyword']}%'";
```

further down the line. Although I do agree that you should probably use WHERE 1 = 1 as that is the most commonly used "always true" condition that gets used when a query is being constructed dynamically :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments.  I have changed the keyowrd to the correct field name DOH! and it is now C_Key_Word so the code now looks like:

Comment: I thought I would add the relevant table structures to help out :)
The primary key is Course_ID
C_Info
-------------
Course_ID
Course_Name
C_Description
C_Duration
C_Cost
C_Entry_Req
C_Assessment_Type
C_Progression
C_Type

C_Search
-------------
Course_ID
C_Key_Words
C_NLC_Ref_No
Awarding_Body
C_UCAS_Code

Answer (score 0):

I think you connection to DB is not set properly kindly check the connection by

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Hi Vineet. His connection is fine. If it wasn't, the script would have died because his connection attempt has "or die (mysql_error())" attached to it.

Comment: @WayneWhitty he is not added table in connection string might be wrong table name

Comment: That might be true. Just pointing out that his connection is fine. There's a difference between connecting to MySQL and selecting a database. The term "connecting to DB" might be confusing to a newcomer.

Comment: @WayneWhitty My English is not such strong but you can change it with appropriate words. Every thing seems ok is code only thing is connection appears bad..